# Looking for recommendations for load testing a complex a system where activity is based on a monthly report

Tags: c#, performance-testing

I am looking for recommendations for perf / load testing a complex system. At the moment we are using jmeter, but the test plans are getting increasingly difficult to implement and maintain, so we are looking for other options, even for design / implement our own tool.

Let's take the following as an example, to describe a similar system what we have.

Take an example HR system with around 460 clients connecting to it. There are employees in the system in different groups and the clients can use to execute different operations on them, like Fire them, Hire them, Renew their contract by X years, transfer them to a different clients, etc.

We are already using jmeter for perf testing the different operations and the mix of operations and that is fine, but we would like to have a more specific way of defining the transactions and their throughput.

After every months the system generates a transaction report for the system, containing all the clients and all their interaction with the employee groups, with the counts of the different transactions on them.

We would like to have a tool which is using the report as an input, and repeats the type of transactions in the system. It could calculate the TPS for each transactions from the report, and use that during the tests.

We are thinking about the following options:

1. Having the full solution in jmeter. Using groovy to process the report, calculate the TPS needed for each type of operations, and use an external source (for example redis) to get the data for the operations (like employees, clients, etc). This is similar to what we do at the moment, but it would increase the complexity with groovy scripts and more involved initial data setup for the different transactions.
2. Completely design and implement our own tool. At the moment for most of the stuff we use C#, so probably we would try to use that as well. With this we might have more control over the transaction distribution and we would expect it to be easier to maintain, however we would loose some great feature from jmeter, like the easy distribution of the load between slave machines.
3. We could do something in between. We could have a tool that sucks in the monthly report file and generates or updates a jmeter test plan with specific setup for the transactions and prepopulating the redis database with inputs for the tests. We would still use jmeter for the actual testing, but we would have a tool for processing the input and setting up the tests.

I would greatly appreciate any input or recommendations you might have, if you encountered similar problems in the past. Do you have any recommendations of any other tool we might find useful for the task above?

Thanks, Tamas